# Gatling2: Get response body as byte array

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to send a request and will receive a byte[] body response. Based on this byte[] response I want to extract a value (using protobuf) and the reuse this value in another resquest.

After some hours search, I cannot find a possibility to extract the http response body as a byte array:

```
   val httpConfig = http
    .baseURL("http://www.whatever.com")

   val request = exec(http("FirstRequest")
    .post("/message")
    .body(new ByteArrayBody((session: Session) => getFirstRequest(session)))
      .check(status.is(200), ???getByteResponse???))

   val response = exec(http("SecondRequest")
    .post("/message")
    .body(new ByteArrayBody((session: Session) => getSecondRequest(session)))
    .check(status.is(200), ???getByteResponse???))

   val scn = scenario("Request").exec(request,response)

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnce(1 user)))
    .protocols(httpConfig)
```

Alternatively it would also be fine if I could set a value in getFirstRequest, that I can reuse in getSecondRequest:

```
private def getFirstRequest(session: Session): Array[Byte] = {

    ... setting a session attribute ... (long)

    ... some protobuf stuff returning a byte array ...  

  }

  private def getSecondRequest(session: Session): Array[Byte] = {
      var value= session("value").as[Long]

    ... some protobuf stuff using value from session and then returning byte array...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like this :

```
.check(status.is(200), bodyBytes.saveAs("responseBody"))
```

This will save the body of the response in the virtual user's session.